# Is there a Selectivity Clause to inject selectivity directly in PostgreSQL similar to IBM DB2

Tags: sql, postgresql

IBM DB2 supports a [`selectivity` clause](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0312yip/) to provide additional selectivity information along with basic predicates to assist query optimization:

> The SELECTIVITY clause can only be used with basic predicates (as
>   defined in the SQL reference), not predicates such as LIKE or BETWEEN.
>   A lower selectivity value (very small number) will tell DB2 that the
>   predicate will qualify fewer rows (and encourage use of indexes
>   defined on that column). A higher selectivity value (close to 1) will
>   mean the opposite.

An example from the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0312yip/):

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, FROM T1, T2, T3
        WHERE T1.x = T2.x AND
        T2.y=T3.y AND
        T1.x >= ? selectivity 0.00001 AND
        T2.y > ? selectivity 0.5 AND
        T3.z = ? selectivity 0.2 AND
        T3.w = ?
```

I am looking for a similar feature in PostgreSQL by which we can inject selectivity of each predicate or at least selectivity at relation level directly as part of query. Does there exist one? Or is there any on-going work on this front? If there is no ongoing work on this, How should I start implementing this feature?

Additional Note: Selectivity = cardinality/(number of records). Selectivity induced by a predicate is the fraction of tuples in the table that are satisfying the predicate. Selectivity of relation depends on selectivity of all predicates involving the relation in the query.

Comment: Why do you need such clause? Maybe all you would need to do is keep the statistics more up to date? (At least I never needed to use that clause under DB2)

Comment: I am working on the selectivity estimation problem of databases optimizers. majorly on PostgreSQL. These selectivity injection feature will be very helpful for my experiments

Comment: And you want the Postgresql developers to search for what is selectivity in DB2 so they can answer you? Can't you explain it in your question?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Is n't it clear from the question that selectivity clause allows specifying selectivity directly for each predicate in the query itself

Comment: So what is selectivity in DB2? Please add that to the question not to a commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a similar feature in PostgreSQL by which we can inject selectivity of each predicate or at least selectivity at relation level directly as part of query. Does there exist one?

There's nothing like that for operators.

For tables you can modify `pg_statistic`, but that only lets you fake stats within the limits provided for by the stats model. Ror example, since PostgreSQL doesn't attempt to identify inter-column correlations it has no place to store info like that and no way to look it up.

> Is there any on-going work on this front?

None I'm aware of. A post to the pgsql-hackers mailing list might find more info.

> If there is no ongoing work on this, How should I start implementing this feature?

Again, I'd raise it on pgsql-hackers. Before you do so, though, do some reading about the PostgreSQL's community's policy about query hints.

There's precedent for cost hinting (see the `COST` term for `CREATE FUNCTION`) and for overriding the estimates from `ANALYZE`. So I think you should be able to make some traction here, though you should expect a lot of bike-shedding on syntax.

Comment: Also - you'll want to start with the parser, adding a new clause. There'll be significant pressure to do so without adding a new keyword - in fact I'd say that a new keyword here will make it nearly impossible to get it accepted.

Comment: I will do some study on this in PostgreSQL source then get back to you. Thanks